# Чи можна вживати слово "зараз", якщо оповідь ведеться в минулому часі?

Tags: вживання-слів

Питання таке: чи можна уживати "зараз" (у значенні "у даний момент", "тепер"), якщо наратив оповідання ведеться в минулому часі. Нижче вставляю абзац з оповідання.

> Підіймаючись пилкою стежкою, юнак та дівчина почали віддалятися від
> гучного сонму, що згромадився на початку галявини. Пара кумедних
> ряжених фігурок — вони не дуже відрізнялися від інших екстравагантних
> проходжалих на центральному пішнику. В неї — лілова в білу цяточку
> сукенка-бандо, великі золотисті конго; в нього — барвисті клаптеві
> аладіни та в’язаний сак на довгому ремінці поверх голого торсу. Вона —
> шістнадцятирічна, вельми приваблива, з милим кирпатим носиком та
> відповідною своєму прізвиську зачіскою. Він — сімнадцятирічний,
> рослявий, зазвичай поважний, але **зараз** — зі скляними очима та
> безглуздою усмішкою.

Прислівник "зараз" за моїм задумом протиставляється словам "зазвичай поважний". Тож виходить так: Марк зазвичай (взагалі) поважний, але в цей конкретний момент, про який зараз розповідається, хлопець має скляні очі та безглуздий погляд. В контексті оповідання начебто зрозуміло, що йдеться не про момент мовлення, а про умовне теперішнє в рамках історії. Будь ласка, виправте мене, якщо я десь помиляюся.

Answer (score 1):

Не можна. Бо це не "зараз", "зараз" може сказати лише той, хто бачить це і говорить тоді ж, а не говорить про побачене раніше.

Це як:
*Він був втомлений, а зараз готовий працювати.* // Розповідамоємо про те, що було вчора. Не можна так.

Як виправити:
"Тоді" не звучить, а "на той момент" — нормально.

Не треба тире після "зараз", бо воно замість "він" і тоді протиставляються прості речення (а не те, що треба). Тобто це тире перетворює просте речення на складне, цікавий випадок.